# RSPEC Redirect_To Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

greeting all--
I'm new to rspec testing and am following the everydayrailsrspec pdf by Aaron Sumner.  I am running into a problem with a redirect_to in my controller test.  I'm testing my create action in my customers controller.  When a record is created, I redirect to my 'list' action.  Trying to test this is giving me fits.

My rspec controller test:

```
describe 'POST #create' do
  context "with valid attributes" do
    it "saves the new customer in the database" do
      expect{
        post :create, customer: attributes_for(:customer)
      }
    end

    it "redirects to list page" do
      post :create, customer: attributes_for(:customer)
      expect(response).to redirect_to(:action => list)
    end
  end
end
```

The, "it saves..." test passes, but the redirect one does not.  In the pdf it shows an example  using a 'customer_url'.   I got the syntax I used (above) from http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec-rails/1.1.12/classes/Spec/Rails/Matchers.html, but it is not working for me.

Error output:

Failures:

```
1) CustomersController while signed in POST #create with valid attributes redirects to list page
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(:action => list)
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `customer' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_5::Nested_1:0x007fdcbfe88f20>
```

I've tried adding the controller name to the test as in >> redirect_to(:controller => customers, :action => list), but it also fails.

Help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying that `"customer is not defined"`. I asume you are using FactoryGirl and you have a `customer` factory defined. If this is right, then you left out the `Factory` method in the `customer` hash

```
it "redirects to list page" do
  post :create, customer: Factory.attributes_for(:customer)
  expect(response).to redirect_to(:action => list)
end
```

You could also write it like this

```
it "redirects to list page" do
  post :create, customer: Factory.attributes_for(:customer)
  response.should redirect_to(:action => list)
end
```

Additionally, on the first test I would suggest adding

```
it "saves the new customer in the database" do
  expect{
    post :create, customer: Factory.attributes_for(:customer)
  }.to change(Customer,:count).by(1)
end
```

this should get you on the right track

Comment: Thank for the help, but that does not do it, sorry.  I do have a factory for customer. I also have a line in my spec_helper.rb:   # Include Factory Girl syntax to simplify calls to factories 
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods       This allows me to not have to use Factory in my create or build statements.  If I remove the second 'it' block, all the tests pass as they are.  But this one will not.  Also, adding 'Factory' gets me an error:  'uninitialized constant Factory'  I do have 'require spec_helper' in my spec.

Comment: how can I add a new-line so I can add formatted code to these comments?  If I hit the Return key, it submits my comment.

Comment: use backticks ` `example` instead of ' 'example'

Comment: I would take out the `# Include Factory Girl syntax to simplify calls to factories config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods` and just write it out until you really understand what is going on with rspec and factorygirl. Also, here is a [link to an article](http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html) by the same author you mention. It is esentially the same as I showed in my answer. My best guess is something is going on with the way you have your factory set up. Can you post all relevant factory girl files?

Comment: Will read the article by Aaron Sumner.  Below are my entries for factoryGirl.  Hopefully enough.  Thanks for your time.
 
My Customer factory

'code' 
    require 'faker'

    FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :customer do
        business_name "Parts R Us"
        contact_name "John"
        address "1 Stewart Ave"
        city "Cortland"
        state "NY"
        zip "13045"
        customer_type "Contractor"
        email { Faker::Internet.email }
        phone { Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number }
      end
    end
'/code'

Comment: sorry, cannot figure out formatting in comments.   
Entry in config/application.rb
 
'code'    
    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec,
        fixtures: true,
        view_specs: false,
        helper_specs: false,
        routing_specs: false,
        controller_specs: true,
        request_specs: true
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: "spec/factories"
    end
'code'

Comment: I added expects{...} around my second test inside the 'it "redirects to list page" do block.  The test passes.  That is not in the pdf.  The site you listed looks like it was extracted from the pdf I am reading through.   Thanks for your help.   Very much appreciated.